# Сохранение нашего языка

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, общие-вопросы

Что допустимо и недопустимо на радио, телевидении?

Answer (score 2):

Допустимо все, что разрешено по законам страны вещания. Если брать РФ, то в контексте русского языка в СМИ законодательно запрещена только матерная лексика, что, по-моему, делать было не нужно, следовательно все остальное разрешено. Другое дело, что редакторы СМИ часто вводят дополнительные ограничения для своих работников, в том числе и на уровне языковых норм. В целом, за то, что позволительно в эфире, голосует сам зритель, рейтингом тех передач, где что-либо допускается.